# modal using prototype in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

How to open an iframe modalbox in a rails app using the prototype javascript library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not prototype, but I will use leigeber's TinyBox: http://www.leigeber.com/2009/05/javascript-popup-box/

Answer (score 1):

http://livepipe.net/control/window is a prototype library has good support for iframes in modal windows and can be used with javascript something like this:

html:

```
<a href='http://example.com/iframe'>click me!</a>
```

javascript:

```
var modal = new Control.Modal($('modal'),{  
    overlayOpacity: 0.75,  
    className: 'modal',  
    fade: true,
    iframe: true  
});
```

Which will open the href of a link with the id of `model` in a lightbox